# Can't clear a window when using setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to clear `setTimeOut()` when button clicked, but screen keep log me in directly even when i add `clearTimeOut`,
here is function i use

```
 function LoginScreen({ navigation, props }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const Login = useSelector(state => {
    return state.loginStatus
  })

  function handleLogin() {
    dispatch({ type: 'changeLogin' })
  }
  function handlDefault() {
    dispatch({ type: 'getDefault' })
  }

  let timeID
  function SetTimer() {
    handleLogin()
    timeID=setTimeout(() => {
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    }, 5000)
  }
  function clearTO() {
    clearTimeout(timeID)
    dispatch({ type: 'getDefault' });
    
  }
```

Basically i want after pressing the login button, a `Modal` window will appear and show the login effect and in that window there is a `button` that when pressed, the login will be paused, however i can't stop the `setTimeOut`, the screen keeps logging in automatically, error like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O34UN.gif)
, please help, thank you a lot

Comment: Everytime your LoginScreen is rendered timeID might have a new value, so your previous timeID might be leaked. You probably need to add this logic to an useEffect with a return value to run this logic of clearTimeout and add timeID to a state. Something like `const [timeID, setTimeID] = React.useState(null)`

Comment: Thank for your reply, can you tell in more detail? Im very new to react and react-native also,  i know hooks, but how can i use it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `React.useRef` to make this variable timeID never lose its value.
You will probably need to handle multiple clicks on the button too, to avoid activating multiple setTimeout.

Observation: You can try a similar logic with useState + useEffect, but it will probably need some useCallback and make the logic more complex

Visual example here: https://snack.expo.io/LYVlrY4_l

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Pressable, View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function Login({ navigation }) {
  const timeIdRef = React.useRef(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
        if (timeIdRef.current) {
          // make sure this is always cleared in case clearTo is never called
          clearTimeout(timeIdRef.current)
        }
      }
  }, [timeIdRef])

  function handleLogin() {
    console.log('handleLogin')
  }

  function SetTimer() {
    handleLogin();
    if (timeIdRef.current) {
      // clear any previous timeIdRef to avoid multiple button click activate multiple setTimeout
      clearTimeout(timeIdRef.current)
    }
    const timeID = setTimeout(() => {
      navigation.navigate("Home");
    }, 5000);
    timeIdRef.current =  timeID
  }

  function clearTO() {
    clearTimeout(timeIdRef.current);
    timeIdRef.current = null
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.ViewStyle}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>Login To System</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', padding: 8}} onPress={SetTimer}>
        <Text>START timer</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
       <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', padding: 8}} onPress={clearTO}>
        <Text>STOP timer</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ViewStyle: {
    alignItems: "center",
    display: "flex",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
});

function Home({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Welcome to Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
     <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```